# What's tropical about tropical algebra?

Tags: terminology, ho.history-overview, soft-question

Please allow me to ask a potentially dumb question (or maybe more precisely, a question floating on clouds of ignorance):

> Why is a max-plus algebra called a *tropical algebra*?

Comment: tropical refers to Brazil. Imre Simon working in Brazil was a pioneer of the field. 

Comment: I see! But surely max-plus was studied even before Imre, or not?

Comment: He was working at Sa\~o Paulo, I believe, and I think that this city is a little bit below the Capricorn tropic!!

Comment: Warning: some Japanese authors use "tropicalization" to refer to lifting a max-plus formula to a rational function, which is what most Western authors call "detropicalization". I think the Japanese point of view makes better sense, in that a max-plus formula is like a zero Kelvin version, like Kashiwara's crystal basis. But it seems unlikely to be uprooted now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A lot of sources mention that the adjective "tropical" is given in honor of Imre Simon, but it seems hard to find who precisely coined the term. I found some sources which attribute this to some French mathematicians. [Here](http://bit-player.org/2009/treats-tropiques) is what Bryan Hayes writes on the topic:

> For starters, what is that word “tropical” supposed to mean? [Speyer and Sturmfels](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408099) explain: “The adjective tropical was coined by French mathematicians, including Jean-Eric Pin, in honor of their Brazilian colleague Imre Simon.” Pin, in a 1998 paper ([.pdf](http://www.liafa.jussieu.fr/~jep/PDF/tropical.pdf)), deflects the credit to another French mathematician, Dominique Perrin, again noting that the name honors “the pioneering work of our brazilian colleague and friend Imre Simon.” Simon himself, in a 1988 paper ([.ps](http://www.ime.usp.br/~is/papir/rmts.ps)), attributes the term to yet a third French mathematician, Christian Choffrut. Apparently, no one wants to lay claim to the word, and I can’t entirely blame them. Speyer and Sturmfels go on: “There is no deeper meaning in the adjective ‘tropical’. It simply stands for the French view of Brazil.”

Answer (score 4):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_geometry:

> The adjective tropical is given in honor of the Brazilian mathematician
>       Imre Simon, who pioneered the field.

Comment: Grazie! I should have read the article on "tropical geometry"; but it seems that max-plus had been around even before Imre?

Comment: Given the name of the guy, why is it not called ``Balaton Geometry''?

Comment: A detailed history of the subject is given in:
http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0507/0507014v1.pdf

According to this survey, the first example of the kind was given by S.C. Kleene (1956), while a systematic treatment of idempotent linear algebra and related subjects was initiated by V.P. Maslov in 1980s. However his approach was analytic, not geometrical, thus the tropical geometry was rediscovered a decade later.

Comment: Igor, would you like something you invented be called Russian? :P